# nested if else shorthand not working properly

Tags: php

I've tried the shorthand but it's now working properly on me please help me to solve this problem thank you.

```
$acc = "free";

echo $limit = $acc == "free" ? 5 : $acc == "muyip" ? 50 : 1000;
```

My expected result is 5 but the result is 50

Comment: PHP 7.4 gives a hint _Deprecated: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`_

Comment: From manual: *Note:

It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious*

Comment: Thank you so much It's working properly now

Comment: A switch/case statement would probably be much better and much cleaner here.

Answer (score 2):

use brackets as below

```
$acc = "free";

echo $limit = $acc == "free" ? 5 : ($acc == "muyip" ? 50 : 1000);
```